# Naming convention for variables to avoid using reserved words

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I was wondering if there is a naming convention for variables that represent a reserved word. For example, I have class called `Video` and this video must contain a boolean defining whether it's private or not.
Since `private boolean private;`would not work, I wonder what the best option was.

- mPrivate
- _private
- isPrivate
- notPublic
- ...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have seen for a variable name clazz for Class

Comment: Why not name it `restricted`? Otherwise I would go with `nonPublic`.

Comment: Anything but Hungarian notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can think of a two-word name, you're clear of any conflict:

- `private` -> `isPrivate`
- `new` -> `newItem`
- ...

Plus, it will often be more readable.

The only common name conflict I'm seeing regularly is the `class` -> `clazz` mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

isPrivate sounds good enough for your situation. I always tend to name my boolean variables like that:

isSomething

hasSomething

etc..

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a `boolean` I think using `isPrivate` is the best option, since it implies that the variable is of boolean value. It is also better than `notPublic` since the "true" value better reflects the name.

mPrivate looks like a name of some `Private` object that you have so I'd stay away from that.
So in conclusion I think `isPrivate` is your best choice

Answer (score 1):

In this case it might be overkill to introduce an enum if true/false are the only choices. (In the following example the problem with reserved words is avoided by using upper case words in the enum.)

```
public class Video {
public enum Access {
    PRIVATE, RESTRICTED, PUBLIC;
}

private String name;
private Access access;

public Video(String name, Access access) {
    this.name = name;
    this.access = access;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Video("Alien", Access.PUBLIC);
    new Video("Home movie", Access.PRIVATE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put what the instance variable represents. i.e your class is Video and the instance variable you want is "private", which you cant use so just call it something like privateVideo. So your getter and setter would be something like isPrivateVideo, setPrivateVideo